# Discord bot Help commands not working Nodejs

Tags: node.js, discord

Not sure if it's my code or it's my permissions for the bot, as this is my first time making a bot. I have added the bot to my server and have it running but the commands are not showing up at all with using the `?` command.

Currently I have the bot permissions as

Scopes: Bot Message.read and Applications.commnds

Then permissions as admin.

```
const {Client, IntentsBitField} = require ('discord.js');

const client = new Client ({
    intents: [
      IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
      IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
      IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
      IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    ],
});

const PREFIX = '?';

const heroInfo = {
  'jack': {
    description: 'A mischievous and agile hero with a quick wit.',
    image: 'URL_TO_IMAGE',
    abilities: ['Ability 1: Sneaky Strike', 'Ability 2: Evasive Roll'],
    faction: 'Rogue',
    emblem: 'URL_TO_EMBLEM_IMAGE',
  },

  // Add more heroes as needed
};

const faqInfo = {
  '9999': '7777',
  'question2': 'Answer to question 2',
  // Add more FAQs as needed
};

const minigameInfo = {
  '99': 'Description of minigame 1',
  '3': 'Description of minigame 2',
  'Skating': 'Description of minigame 3',
  '4': 'Description of minigame 2',
  // Add more minigames as needed
};

const top5PvPTeams = [
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_1',
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_2',
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_3',
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_4',
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_5',
];

const top5PvETeams = [
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_1',
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_2',
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_3',
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_4',
  'URL_TO_TEAM_IMAGE_5',
];

const elementalCityTeams = {
  'fire': {
    dungeon: 'Best team for Fire dungeon',
    hardStage5: 'URL_TO_FIRE_HARD_STAGE_5_IMAGE',
    hardStage10: 'URL_TO_FIRE_HARD_STAGE_10_IMAGE',
    hardStage15: 'URL_TO_FIRE_HARD_STAGE_15_IMAGE',
  },
  'ice': {
    dungeon: 'Best team for Ice dungeon',
    hardStage5: 'URL_TO_ICE_HARD_STAGE_5_IMAGE',
    hardStage10: 'URL_TO_ICE_HARD_STAGE_10_IMAGE',
    hardStage15: 'URL_TO_ICE_HARD_STAGE_15_IMAGE',
  },
  'wood': {
    dungeon: 'Best team for Wood dungeon',
    hardStage5: 'URL_TO_WOOD_HARD_STAGE_5_IMAGE',
    hardStage10: 'URL_TO_WOOD_HARD_STAGE_10_IMAGE',
    hardStage15: 'URL_TO_WOOD_HARD_STAGE_15_IMAGE',
  },
  'water': {
    dungeon: 'Best team for Water dungeon',
    hardStage5: 'URL_TO_WATER_HARD_STAGE_5_IMAGE',
    hardStage10: 'URL_TO_WATER_HARD_STAGE_10_IMAGE',
    hardStage15: 'URL_TO_WATER_HARD_STAGE_15_IMAGE',
  },
  // Add more elemental city teams as needed
};

const bossSpeedInfo = {
  '888': {
    stage26: 'Stage 26 - 2320 speed',
    stage27: 'Stage 27 - 2440 speed',
    stage28: 'Stage 28 - 2560 speed',
    stage29: 'Stage 29 - 2680 speed',
    stage30: 'Stage 30 - 2800 speed',
  },
  '9999': {
    stage35: 'Stage 35 - 2320 speed',
    stage36: 'Stage 36 - 2360 speed',
    stage37: 'Stage 37 - 2420 speed',
    stage38: 'Stage 38 - 2480 speed',
    stage39: 'Stage 39 - 2540 speed',
    stage40: 'Stage 40 - 2620 speed',
  },
  // Add more boss speeds as needed
};

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'hero') {
    const heroName = args.join(' ').toLowerCase();
    const heroData = heroInfo[heroName];

    if (heroData) {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle(heroName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + heroName.slice(1)) // Capitalize the hero name
        .setDescription(heroData.description)
        .addField('Abilities', heroData.abilities.join('\n'))
        .addField('Faction', heroData.faction)
        .addField('Emblem', heroData.emblem)
        .setImage(heroData.image);

      message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('Hero not found. Please check the hero name and try again.');
    }
  } else if (command === 'faq') {
    const question = args.join(' ').toLowerCase();
    const answer = faqInfo[question];

    if (answer) {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Frequently Asked Question')
        .addField('Question', question)
        .addField('Answer', answer);

      message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('FAQ not found. Please check the question and try again.');
    }
  } else if (command === 'minigames') {
    const minigame = args.join(' ').toLowerCase();
    const description = minigameInfo[minigame];

    if (description) {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Minigame Information')
        .setDescription(description);

      message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('Minigame not found. Please check the minigame name and try again.');
    }
  } else if (command === 'top5pvp') {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#ff0000')
      .setTitle('Top 5 PvP Teams')
      .setDescription('Here are the top 5 PvP teams:')
      .setImage(top5PvPTeams.join('\n'));

    message.channel.send(embed);
  } else if (command === 'top5pve') {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#00ff00')
      .setTitle('Top 5 PvE Teams')
      .setDescription('Here are the top 5 PvE teams:')
      .setImage(top5PvETeams.join('\n'));

    message.channel.send(embed);
  } else if (command === 'elementalcity') {
    const dungeon = args[0].toLowerCase();
    const stage = args[1] ? `hardStage${parseInt(args[1])}` : 'dungeon';
    const imageUrl = elementalCityTeams[dungeon] && elementalCityTeams[dungeon][stage];

    if (imageUrl) {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0000ff')
        .setTitle(`Best Team for ${dungeon.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dungeon.slice(1)} Dungeon - ${stage.replace('hardStage', 'Hard Stage ')}`)
        .setImage(imageUrl);

      message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('Dungeon or stage not found. Please check the dungeon and stage and try again.');
    }
  } else if (command === 'speed') {
    const faction = args.join(' ').toLowerCase();
    const speedInfo = bossSpeedInfo[faction];

    if (speedInfo) {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ffcc00')
        .setTitle(`Boss Speeds for ${faction.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + faction.slice(1)}`)
        .setDescription(Object.values(speedInfo).join('\n'));

      message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('Faction not found. Please check the faction name and try again.');
    }
  }
});

client.login('');
```

I need to figure if it's my Discord permissions or code.

Comment: `Applications.commnds` should probably be `Applications.commands`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read [this](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ). The `MessageContent` intent is a privileged intent as of August 31, 2022. You should go to your bot's application's page on the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers) and check if your bot has the message content intent toggled on.